# File Naming, Python

Tags: python, file

What I am trying to do in Python, is make a program where you can write to a file directly from the command line. I have all the code to do this, but the only relevant code is below.

```
aw = input("Do you want to append your text file, or rewrite the whole thing? (append/write) ")
if aw == 'append':
    textin = input("In the line below, write the text you want to put into your text document!\n\n")
    outfile = open('mytext.txt', 'a')
    outfile.write(textin)
```

What I am trying to do is make it so people can choose the filename, but when I do an input function, `name = input("Choose your filename, don't include an extension: ")` and change line 4 into `outfile = open(name, 'txt', 'a')`, I get a syntax error!

Comment: You probably meant to concatenate the name, like `open(name + '.txt', 'a')`. The way you have it would be a problem since `"txt"` would be interpreted as the mode argument to `open()`.

Comment: @birryree: Please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Well my comment might have identified a different problem, but your syntax error was probably something else - can you update to show us what your code looks like when you try to change the `outfile` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead: `outfile = open(name + '.txt', 'a')`

Python cannot concatenate strings like that and so was treating `open(name, 'txt', 'a')` as a function call with three arguments. Unfortunately the `open` function only takes two.

**Edit:** If this is Python 2.x code, then you are also using the `input` function incorrectly. According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) the input function requires the user to type *valid python code*, you are looking for the [`raw_input` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

If this is Python 3.x code, then the correct function is [`input`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) and my apologies.

Comment: Also, the syntax error is probably due to wrong indentation or missing braces or something.

Comment: I've just realised it's because `input` requires the user to type valid Python. Editng my answer.

Comment: If it's Python 3, `input()` is the correct function. If it's Python 2, `raw_input()` would be the right choice.